# TuesPechkin how to get PrintBackground = false to work in VB.NET for ASP.NET webpages

Tags: pechkin

```
@Imports TuesPechkin

Dim WebSettings = New WebSettings()
With WebSettings
   .PrintBackground = False
End With
Dim URL As New Uri("http://www.adelaide.edu.au")
Dim converter As IPechkin = Factory.Create()
Dim result As Byte() = converter.Convert(URL) 
File.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath("") & "\example.pdf", result)
```

Can't work out how to get .PrintBackground = False to work

Answer (score 0):

Where is the websettings object connect to the converter object?

If the two are not connected, it won't make any difference what websettings is set to.